# Clickatell Triggering During Market Days

Tags: clickatell

I am developing an app and I noticed it sometimes sends texts before I click Html link should I be doing this with C# not Html? Also, my project html page is going to wait each day then check metals API(which checks the market mainly metals). I'd like to text myself different messages based on price. Am not planning on releasing this app as I would not because this is for me only. Right now clicking before running is causing it to send too soon.
I put this in a alt link
href="https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=**********==&to=1********&content='Test Alert'"
It should be noted on my end i used my key
My question what javascript object to use for time...and also to make sure i don't send myself too many messages.

Comment: Q: What is your question?  Q: Do you have any code you could post regarding your question?

Comment: the problem is it goes through the link before when i am in editor not chrome

Comment: am clicking my own link but it works also in the editor(when i have not ran it) and i don't know if i should delete this webpage and try again

Comment: it is also doing it more than once....:(

Comment: for now the traffic is off because i did this off the website